# Servlet Not Executing

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am created new Java Enterprise Application in intellij. I created an index.jsp, HelloServlet.java file. when i try to execute its working fine for jsp but the servlet not executing.

My files are like following

HelloServlet.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "/helloServlet", urlPatterns = {"/helloServlet"})


public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private String message;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

index.jsp

[image]

I am tried by changing webservlet annotation to the following:

```
@WebServlet("/helloServlet")

@WebServlet(name="/helloServlet" value="/helloServlet")

@WebServlet(name="/helloServlet" urlPatterns={"/helloServlet"})
```

and i tried with servlet and servlet mapping in web.xml file but its not working.

Used IntellijIDEA, Tomacat 10

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, like your .jsp.

Comment: Tomcat10 is JakartaEE not JaveEE (which you are using). Either change your code to use JakartaEE, or use Tomcat9.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I copy pasted the same code in my ide. I used tomcat 9 where it worked perfectly. In my vision there is know issue in the code. You should either change the tomcat version